# Problemas con el Error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path

Tags: java, json, websocket, restful, jdeveloper

estoy convirtiendo un arreglo json en una lista en java, cuando lo hago desde jDeveloper 12.2.1.4.0, me funciona perfectamente el parseo. haciendolo de la siguiente manera

```
    public List<Paciente> listar(){
        List<Paciente> inpList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

                    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7101/AplicacionServidorHospitalREST-ProyectoServidorHospitalREST-context-root/resources/ServiciosWebRest/listar");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "
                                + conn.getResponseCode());
                    }
                    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                    String output;
                    int i = 0;
                   
                    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                       // System.out.println(i + " - " + output);
                       
                       Type type = new TypeToken<List<Paciente>>() {
                              }.getType();
                        inpList = new Gson().fromJson(output, type);
                       for (int j = 0; i < inpList.size(); i++) {
                                  Paciente x = inpList.get(i);
                                  System.out.println(x.toString());
                        
                              }
                        i++;
                    }
            
                   
                    conn.disconnect();
                  

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception in NetClientGet:- " + e);
                }
        return inpList;
        
    }
```

El array.json lo obtengo de un servidor web restFull que hice en la misma version de jDeveloper, el problema es que cuando hago lo mismo en la version 12.1.3.0 ya no funciona, el json que se genera en cada versión es diferente :

[{"correo":"luis@gmail.com","documento":"66666","genero":"masculino","id":2,"nombre":"Neymar","telefono":"66666"}, Este es de la versión mas reciente de jDeveloper

y este de la versión 12.1.3.0, en donde ya no me funciona el parseo.

{"Paciente":[{"correo":"ggg","documento":"ggg","genero":"ggg","id":"8","nombre":"ggg","telefono":"ggg"}

como ven me devuelve un objeto y no una lista, alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El motivo es complicado de determinar porque no esta el código de los servicios REST para poder verificarlos, ahora para poder realizar la conversión del JSON a un Objeto según el formato de la versión 12.1.3.0 sigue el siguiente ejemplo:

Primero creamos una clase de emboltorio para la lista de Paciente.

```
public class PacienteResponse {
    List <Paciente> Paciente;
}
```

Realice algunos cambios rápidos para corregir complejidad que según analizo no es necesita y un mejor del manejo del cierre de la conexión porque en tu ejemplo si el código fallaba antes de cerrar la conexión iba a quedar abierta y provocar fugas de memoria:

```
public List<Paciente> listar() {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7101/AplicacionServidorHospitalREST-ProyectoServidorHospitalREST-context-root/resources/ServiciosWebRest/listar");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
       
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        // Variable para almacenar el Json, mas optimo que utilizar String para concatenar.
        StringBuilder sbJson = new StringBuilder();
        String output;

        //Aquí hay que acumular el json en caso se envié en varias líneas.
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sbJson.append(output + "\n");
        }
        br.close();

        PacienteResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(sbJson.toString(), PacienteResponse.class);

        if (response != null && !response.getPaciente().isEmpty()) {
            return response.getPaciente();
        }
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in Protocol:- ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in URL:- ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in NetClientGet:- ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Algunos puntos de mejora extra sería crear excepciones personalizadas para no lanzar RuntimeException genericas, dar tratamiento a los error encaso la url o conexión presenten un error y fraccionar en metodos la complejidad de este servicio.